# Human Rate the ICPS on EM-1 of SLS

Tags: rockets, sls, ula, human-rating, compliance

What specifically must be done to Human Rate the Interim Cryogenic Propulsion Stage ([ICPS](https://www.nasa.gov/sls/interim_cryogenic_propulsion_stage_141030.html)) to fly humans on [Exploration Mission 1 of SLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploration_Mission_1)?

Answer (score 2):

Compliance is mandatory!

[Human Rating Requirements for Space Systems](https://nodis3.gsfc.nasa.gov/displayDir.cfm?Internal_ID=N_PR_8705_002B_&page_name=Chapter3)

It's long, even with the rationale scraped out, but here you go.

> **3.2 System Safety Requirements**
>
> 3.2.1 The space system shall provide the capability to sustain a safe, habitable environment for the crew (Requirement 58503).
>
> 3.2.2 The space system shall meet probabilistic safety criteria derived from the Agency-level safety goals and safety thresholds with
> a specified degree of certainty (Requirement).
>
> 3.2.3 The space system shall provide failure tolerance to catastrophic events, with specific levels of failure tolerance and
> implementation (similar or dissimilar redundancy) derived via an
> integration of the design and safety analysis (per the requirement in
> paragraph 2.3.7.1) (Requirement).
>
> a. Failure of primary structure, structural failure of pressure vessel
> walls, and failure of pressurized lines are excepted from the failure
> tolerance requirement provided the potentially catastrophic failures
> are controlled through a defined process in which approved standards
> and margins are implemented that account for the absence of failure
> tolerance.
>
> b. Other potentially catastrophic hazards that cannot be controlled
> using failure tolerance are excepted from the failure tolerance
> requirements with concurrence from the Technical Authorities provided
> the hazards are controlled through a defined process in which approved
> standards and margins are implemented that account for the absence of
> failure tolerance.
>
> 3.2.4 The space system shall provide the failure tolerance capability in 3.2.3 without the use of emergency equipment and systems
> (Requirement 58557).
>
> 3.2.5 The space system shall be designed to tolerate inadvertent operator action (minimum of one inadvertent action), as identified by
> the human error analysis (paragraph 2.3.11), without causing a
> catastrophic event (Requirement 58559).
>
> 3.2.6 The space system shall tolerate inadvertent operator action, as described in 3.2.4, in the presence of any single system failure
> (Requirement 58561).
>
> 3.2.7 The space system shall provide the capability to mitigate the hazardous behavior of critical software where the hazardous behavior
> would result in a catastrophic event (Requirement 58563).
>
> 3.2.8 The space system shall provide the capability to detect and annunciate faults that affect critical systems, subsystems, and/or
> crew health (Requirement 58569).
>
> 3.2.9 The space system shall provide the capability to isolate and/or recover from faults identified during system development that would
> result in a catastrophic event (Requirement 58572).
>
> 3.2.10 The space system shall provide the capability to utilize health and status data (including system performance data) of critical
> systems and subsystems to facilitate anomaly resolution during and
> after the mission (Requirement 58574).
>
> 3.2.11 The crewed space system shall provide the capability for autonomous operation of system and subsystem functions which, if lost,
> would result in a catastrophic event (Requirement 58576).
>
> 3.2.12 The space system shall provide the capability for the crew to readily access equipment involved in the response to emergency
> situations and the capability to gain access to equipment needed for
> follow-up/recovery operations (Requirement 58578).
>
> **3.3 System Control Requirements - General**
>
> 3.3.1 The crewed space system shall provide the capability for the crew to monitor, operate, and control the crewed space system and
> subsystems, where:
>
> a. The capability is necessary to execute the mission; or
>
> b. The capability would prevent a catastrophic event; or
>
> c. The capability would prevent an abort (Requirement).
>
> 3.3.2 The crewed space system shall provide the capability for the crew to manually override higher level software control/automation
> (such as automated abort initiation, configuration change, and mode
> change) when the transition to manual control of the system will not
> cause a catastrophic event (Requirement 58586).
>
> 3.3.3 The space system shall provide the capability for humans to remotely monitor, operate, and control the crewed system elements and
> subsystems, where:
>
> a. The remote capability is necessary to execute the mission; or
>
> b. The remote capability would prevent a catastrophic event; or
>
> c. The remote capability would prevent an abort (Requirement 58598).
>
> **3.4 System Control Requirements - Human-Rated Spacecraft**
>
> 3.4.1 The crewed space system shall provide the capability for the crew to manually control the flight path and attitude of their
> spacecraft, with the following exception: during the atmospheric
> portion of Earth ascent when structural and thermal margins have been
> determined to negate the benefits of manual control (Requirement).
>
> 3.4.2 The crewed spacecraft shall exhibit Level 1 handling qualities (Handling Qualities Rating (HQR) 1, 2 and 3), as defined by the
> Cooper-Harper Rating Scale, during manual control of the spacecraft's
> flight path and attitude (Requirement).
>
> **3.5 System Control Requirements - Proximity Operations with Human-Rated Spacecraft**
>
> 3.5.1 The space system shall provide the capability for the crew to monitor, operate, and control an uncrewed spacecraft during proximity
> operations, where:
>
> a. The capability is necessary to execute the mission; or
>
> b. The capability would prevent a catastrophic event; or
>
> c. The capability would prevent an abort (Requirement 58604).
>
> 3.5.2 The crewed space system shall provide the capability for direct voice communication between crewed spacecraft (2 or more) during
> proximity operations (Requirement 58607).
>
> **3.6 Crew Survival/Abort Requirements**
>
> 3.6.1 Earth Ascent Systems
>
> 3.6.1.1 The space system shall provide the capability for unassisted crew emergency egress to a safe haven during Earth prelaunch
> activities (Requirement 58611).
>
> 3.6.1.2 The space system shall provide abort capability from the launch pad until Earth-orbit insertion to protect for the following
> ascent failure scenarios (minimum list):
>
> a. Complete loss of ascent thrust/propulsion (Requirement 58613).
>
> b. Loss of attitude or flight path control (Requirement 58614).
>
> 3.6.1.3 The crewed space system shall monitor the Earth ascent launch vehicle performance and automatically initiate an abort when an
> impending catastrophic failure is detected (Requirement 58616).
>
> 3.6.1.4 Earth Ascent Abort
>
> 3.6.1.4.1 The space system shall provide the capability for the crew to initiate the Earth ascent abort sequence (Requirement 58619).
>
> 3.6.1.4.2 The space system shall provide the capability for the ground control to initiate the Earth ascent abort sequence (Requirement
> 58620).
>
> 3.6.1.5 If a range safety destruct system is incorporated into the design, the space system shall automatically initiate the Earth ascent
> abort sequence when range safety destruct commands are received
> onboard, with an adequate time delay prior to destruction of the
> launch vehicle to allow a successful abort (Requirement 58622).
>
> 3.6.2 Earth Orbit Systems
>
> 3.6.2.1 The crewed space system shall provide the capability to autonomously abort the mission from Earth orbit by targeting and
> performing a deorbit to a safe landing on Earth (Requirement 58625).
>
> 3.6.3 Earth - Lunar Transit and Lunar Orbit Systems
>
> 3.6.3.1 The crewed space system shall provide the capability to autonomously abort the mission during lunar transit and from lunar
> orbit by executing a safe return to Earth (Requirement 58627).
>
> 3.6.4 Lunar Descent Systems
>
> 3.6.4.1 The crewed space system shall provide the capability to autonomously abort the lunar descent and execute all operations
> required for a safe return to Earth (Requirement 58629).
>
> 3.6.5 Lunar Surface Systems
>
> 3.6.5.1 The space system shall provide the capability for the crew on the lunar surface to monitor the descent and landing trajectory of an
> uncrewed spacecraft and send commands necessary to prevent a
> catastrophic event (Requirement 58632).
>
> 3.6.6 Lunar Ascent Systems
>
> Reserved for a future version of the NPR.
>
> 3.6.7 Earth Reentry Systems
>
> 3.6.7.1 The crewed space system shall provide the capability for unassisted crew emergency egress after Earth landing (Requirement
> 58636).
>
> 3.6.7.2 The crewed space system shall provide a safe haven capability for the crew inside the spacecraft after Earth landing until the
> arrival of the landing recovery team or rescue forces (Requirement
> 58638).
>
> 3.6.7.3 The space system shall provide recovery forces with the location of the spacecraft after return to Earth (Requirement 58640).

Comment: Thank you I had just found that same link in a previous question in Stack Exchange from year ago What I was looking for was because -in the NASA teleconference today (2/24/17) William Gerstenmaier of NASA mentioned to human rate for the EM 1 it would take a "significant" amount of money and budget to do the human rating work on theInterim Cryogenic Propulsion Stage of the SLS after hearing this I was curious what specific work or changes need to be done

Comment: Yeah, these are the requirements.  What the design will be...we don't know yet.